# when using many full text indexes , is there best practices for this usage?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

Hi I have a database with about 100 tables : 
I did a study to create many full text indexes and I found that I need to create about 
70 full text indexes in 70 tables .

since it's the first time I use full text search , I feel it strange or confusing to use all theses full text indexes . is there any best practices ?? is there any performance issue ?